# Something Enables scroll-lock-mode in Emacs

Tags: scroll, emacs, elisp

I have Emacs running in WSL2

```
GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw scroll bars) of 2021-07-20
```

About couple of weeks ago open buffers started getting `scroll-lock-mode` enabled. I have it set to `nil` by default. Moreover, if I disable `scroll-lock-mode` after some time it gets enabled. I don't have anything anywhere in the configuration related to scrolling. I have instrumented `scroll-lock-mode` function, but when it jumps in it, seems to be called from random spots

```
  (let ((last-message (current-message))) (setq scroll-lock-mode (cond ((eq arg 'toggle) (not scroll-lock-mode)) ((and (numberp arg) (< arg 1)) nil) (t t))) (when (boundp 'local-minor-modes) (setq local-minor-modes (delq 'scroll-lock-mode local-minor-modes)) (when scroll-lock-mode (push 'scroll-lock-mode local-minor-modes))) (if scroll-lock-mode (progn (setq scroll-lock-preserve-screen-pos-save scroll-preserve-screen-position) (setq-local scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always)) (setq scroll-preserve-screen-position scroll-lock-preserve-screen-pos-save)) (run-hooks 'scroll-lock-mode-hook (if scroll-lock-mode 'scroll-lock-mode-on-hook 'scroll-lock-mode-off-hook)) (if (called-interactively-p 'any) (progn nil (unless (and (current-message) (not (equal last-message (current-message)))) (let ((local " in current buffer")) (message "Scroll-Lock mode %sabled%s" (if scroll-lock-mode "en" "dis") local))))))
  scroll-lock-mode(toggle)
  funcall-interactively(scroll-lock-mode toggle)
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> scroll-lock-mode nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (scroll-lock-mode nil nil))
  call-interactively(scroll-lock-mode nil nil)
  command-execute(scroll-lock-mode)
```

Here's the sample of the *Messages* buffer

```
Scroll-Lock mode enabled in current buffer
Scroll-Lock mode disabled in current buffer
GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw scroll bars) of 2021-07-20
Mark set
Scroll-Lock mode enabled in current buffer
```

How to I make it disabled for good ? I used `(setq-default scroll-lock-mode nil)` but it is still being enabled by something.

Comment: I also recognize that some kind of scroll-lock is enabled on my emacs (27.1 on Debian via WLS2) and eventually found out that scroll-lock-mode is enabled. What disturbs me more is that after I manually disable the scroll-lock-mode, it is automatically enabled again whenever I switch away the focus from the emacs window. I also want to know what's going on. And scroll-lock-mode being ("by itself") enabled shows in the message buffer.

Answer (score 0):

disabling Scroll_lock ends the behavior

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<Scroll_Lock>") nil)
```

linking the key back to scroll-lock-mode will let this problem re-emerge.

I haven't really figured out what's behind such erroneous auto trigger of scroll-lock-mode though.